# cv2.imshow() doesnt work when easyocr installed

Tags: python, opencv, easyocr

I installed `easyocr` in a newly created python environment using `pip` install `easyocr`.
Then i installed `opencv-python`.

when i try to execute the code -

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
cv2.imshow('sd',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It's giving error

> OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1268: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 11 OS @TimRoberts

Comment: I suggest you delete your environment and create a new one, then install those packages in the opposite order.  Perhaps `easyocr` installed `opencv-python-headless`, which does not do graphics.

Comment: Yeah, I faced the same issue after installing `easyocr`. You could still use `matplotlib` to show images.

Comment: @TimRoberts - Installed the packages in the opposite order. Same Issue.

Comment: @DevdroneBhowmik Can you try uninstalling `opencv-python-headless` and then install `opencv-python` in the same environment?

Comment: @JeruLuke - This worked. Let me deploy this in my full code and will update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Problem:

If you already have an existing `OpenCV` version in your system/environment; installing `easyOCR` can alter that. Going through the [`requirements.txt file`](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR/blob/master/requirements.txt) of `easyOCR`, `opencv-python-headless` gets installed.

The following excerpt is taken from [`opencv-python-headless` documentation](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python-headless/):

> Packages for server (headless) environments (such as Docker, cloud environments etc.), no GUI library dependencies

> These packages are smaller than the two other packages above because they do not contain any GUI functionality (not compiled with Qt / other GUI components). This means that the packages avoid a heavy dependency chain to X11 libraries and you will have for example smaller Docker images as a result. You should always use these packages if you do not use cv2.imshow et al. or you are using some other package (such as PyQt) than OpenCV to create your GUI.

#### **TLDR;**

In short, `easyocr` disables existing GUI capabilities. It has been designed exclusively for containerized applications and/or server deployments.

#### Solution:

To use `easyOCR` with `OpenCV`, you can try either one of the following:

**1. Change installation sequence:**

All the following can be done using `pip`:

- First install `easyocr`.
- Uninstall `opencv-python-headless`.
- Install `opencv-python`

**2. Use `matplotlib`**

One can still display images using `matplotlib`:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg',0)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```